# Update PHP 7.2.19 to 7.2.24 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 server

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates, php

When I run apt-get update I get the following:

```
Hit:1 http://mirror.23media.de/mariadb/repo/10.3/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/brightbox/ruby-ng/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/development/ubuntu bionic InRelease
```

Running sudo apt-get dist-upgrade I can't get php to update from 7.2.19 to 7.2.24, which doesn't have the vulnerabilities discovered a few days ago.

How could I do that? Thank you all!

P.S. Running php-v gets me:

```
    PHP 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (cli) (built: Aug 12 2019 19:34:28) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: May I ask why you need 7.2.24 specifically?  Security issues addressed in 7.2.24 are already actively backported to the older 7.2.19 in 18.04.

Comment: @ThomasWard I thought 7.2.19 was vulnerable and we need to update 7.2.X to 7.2.24 asap

Comment: No, 7.2.19 in the Repositories is patched regularly by the Security Team.  https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/pkg/php7.2.html details the remaining CVEs that are unpatched in the package (see the Bionic column).  The Security team will patch security issues as they can, so it's not necessary to do a full software version upgrade *just* to get patched versions.  Do you have specific CVEs/vulnerabilities you're interested in seeing if the PHP in Ubuntu 18.04 is patched for?

Comment: What you have is *not* 7.2.19; it is 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2.

Comment: @fkraiem thank you! Now I know where to look for when the patch comes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that fix for CVE-ID: 2019-11043 which is on the mainstream PHP 7.2.24 has not made it yet to the php7.2 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 version that is maintained by the Ubuntu team:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php7.2/7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2

https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2019/CVE-2019-11043.html

So I guess we need to wait a little more for it.

Comment: It's in progress, according to my contacts on the Security team

Comment: Thank you for the message that makes it clear for me! Also to @ThomasWard for helping out.

Comment: Update: today dist-upgrade gave a package upgrade for PHP from php7.2 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 to 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1. Here is my current php -v print:
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2019 12:07:07) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies